# RestTemplate Test w specific parameters for REST Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, resttemplate

I am writing Integration Tests for controllers using RestTemplate, so far I have been able to call most , however haven't been able to tackle this particular parameter combination.

I know how to deal with headers, GET or PUT parameters, but multiple String is sole one that have yet to figure. Dunno if @Annotations make difference.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getBook", method = GET)   
@ResponseStatus(OK)   
public @ResponseBody  
GetBookResponse getBook(@RequestParam("isbnID") String isbnID, @RequestParam(required=false) Double price, @RequestHeader(required=false) String publisher)                                                             
     {
.....
}
```

and how this would work in the case for POST

Normally I use ResponseEntity to get response but been stuck pn how to prep it.

Comment: What do you mean by `multiple String`

Comment: I would suggest if you want to test the controller, then you should use the normal way of testing in which it will boot up the server/create a context and then you mock the request and check for that request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically we create a new HttpRequest and add the request parameters to it and submit your HttpRequest with all its corresponding parameters in your post. I don't know how to implement it with the framework you are using though. I've written tests for controllers and this is how I did it. GET request usually has just one parameter in the url so you don't really have to add request parameters but POST should have request parameters set to the httpRequest.